# Select Parent Node without Child node. XSLT

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I would like to select Parent node without Child node.

Example:

```
<Shop>
    <Product>
       <ProductId>1</ProductId>
       <Description>ProductList</Description> 
       <Milk>
         <MilkId></MilkId>
       </Milk>
    </Product>
</Shop>
```

Desired Output:

```
<Shop>
    <Product>
       <ProductId>1</ProductId>
       <Description>ProductList</Description> 
    </Product>
</Shop>
```

I tried below XSLT but it failed to return correct result:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="//Product/not[Milk]"/>
```

Thank you for any help.

**Update:**

XSLT:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="Product/*[not(self::Milk)]" />
```

Returns:

```
<ProductId>1</ProductId>
```

I need below structure to be returned:

```
<Shop>
        <Product>
           <ProductId>1</ProductId>
           <Description>ProductList</Description> 
        </Product>
    </Shop>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variant of the *Identity template*:

```
<!-- Identity template variant -->
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[local-name()!='Milk']|@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Or, as a more XSLT-2.0 way suggested in the comments

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() except Milk|@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

It copies all nodes except for the ones named `Milk` and its children.

---

If you want to apply this only to `Product` nodes, you also have to use the *Identity template* and change the matching rule to

```
<xsl:template match="Product">...
```

---

A solution using only `xsl:copy-of` could be copying the `Product` element and then copy all of its children (except for the `Milk` ones) with

```
<xsl:copy-of select="Product/*[not(self::Milk)]" />
```

Or, in a whole XSLT-2.0 template

```
<xsl:template match="//Product">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="* except Milk" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

---

A whole XSLT-1.0 stylesheet could look like

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <!-- Identity template -->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
             <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template> 

    <xsl:template match="Product">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:copy-of select="*[not(self::Milk)]" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Its output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Shop>
    <Product>
        <ProductId>1</ProductId>
        <Description>ProductList</Description>
    </Product>
</Shop>
```

Comment: Is it not possible to just use <xsl:copy-of select>? Thank you!

Comment: I updated my answer. (I guess that the last variant fits best your needs)

Comment: As this is tagged as XSLT 2, I think using `node() except Milk` is a much more idiomatic way to express the requirements than comparing local name.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I'm looking for: <xsl:copy-of select="Product/*[not(self::Milk)]" />. However, for some reasons, it just returns one node: "<ProductId>1</ProductId>" without <Description>ProductList</Description> and <Product> parent node is also missing. Also I made a small change. My example should also have one more node.

Comment: I updated my answer again with an XSLT-1.0 solution.